# Probability of continues samples being equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I want to check if the following statment is true.

Let $X_{1}$ being a realization from a Normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. This $X_{1}$ is an element of the $\mathbb{R}.$

Let $X_{2}$ a second realization of the $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$.

If I want to find the probability that the $X_{2}$ coincides with $X_{1}$, $\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=X_{1})$, it is equivalent to calculate the probability of picking the $X_{1}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ which is zero.

Hence, the probability of two different realization of a continues distribution being equal is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presuming $X_1, X_2$ are single observations

$$\forall_{t_0 \in \mathbb{R}}P(X_2=t_0|X_1=t_0) = P(t_0)=0$$ this is true for continuous support, for not continuous support variables(discrete) it wouldn't have to be true
$$P(X_2=X_1)=\int_\mathbb{R}P(X_2=t|X_1=t)p(t)dt = \int_\mathbb{R}0\ p(t)dt = 0$$